# When i kill the application in multitasking bar,and run the program it's goes to same state where i was closing the app

Tags: iphone

Today i updated my 3GS i-phone to install my application to see it's functioning well in OS4,when i'm running the application and tap the home button it's goes to multitasking bar,then again i get the application from there it's goes to previous state where i was.i think the behavior is OK. but problem comes when i kill the application in multitasking bar and run it it's come to same state,simply it's ignore the login screen.

My question is when i kill the application i want to get my login screen, not the previous state, this application is working fine in 3GS,can some one please help me to fix this issue?

Thanks
Sam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sam,

If you don't want the OS to save state for you, you should place the key `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` in your info.plist file.

More information here:  http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW23

This will kill the app when the home button is pressed, instead of suspending it into the background (which is what iOS4 does for multi-tasking).